# $1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{x_n}\geq n$. Determine $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $x_n$ be the smallest natural number such that:
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{x_n}\geq n$$
Determine $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$

It's the harmonic series but I can't figure when does the harmonic sum overcomes a number. I've done a script that finds the first 5 numbers from the sequence but I can't find a formula between them.
$$x_1=1\\x_2=4\\x_3=11\\x_4=31\\x_5=81$$
I believe it has to do something with exponential but I am not sure (from it's growth)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Where did you get those values? The inequality $1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n\geqslant n$ *never* holds when $n>1$. I suspect that you are using the symbol $n$ with two distinct meanings.

Comment: ```python
s = 0
n = 1
for i in range(1,100):
    s+=(1/i)
    if s>=n:
        print(i)
        n+=1
    if n>5:
        break
```

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question intead of posting a piece of python code. Otherwise, it will be closed.

Comment: You mean post the code in the question or no code at all?

Comment: No code at all. Just correct your question. As it is, *it makes no sense*.

Comment: The last term it's not $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Makes sense now, I think ? $x_n$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{j} \geq n$. This is well-defined because the harmonic series diverges

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense.

Comment: So that limit is equal to infinity?

Comment: I think $x_5$ should be 83

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will use the fact that for large $x_k$

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_k}- \log(x_k)\right)=\gamma$$

where $\gamma=0.577216$. Now, since

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_k}=0$$

we know that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_k}-k)=0$$

---

EDIT: More details were requested for this step.

First, define

$$H_{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$$

Then we know that

$$H_{x_k}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_k}\geq k$$

and

$$H_{x_k-1}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_k-1}\leq k$$

This implies

$$H_{x_k-1}\leq k\leq H_{x_k}$$

Thus

$$ 0=H_{x_k}-H_{x_k}\leq H_{x_k}-k\leq H_{x_k}-H_{x_k-1}=\frac{1}{x_k}$$

Since $x_k\geq k$ (and therefore goes to infinity) we know

$$0\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}(H_{x_k}-k)\leq \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{x_k}\leq \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}=0$$

We conclude

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}(H_{x_k}-k)=0$$

---

This implies

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\log(x_{k+1})-\log(x_k)\right)$$

$$=\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_{k+1}}\right)-\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_k}\right)\right)$$

$$=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left((k+1)-k\right)=1$$

Thus

$$1=\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\log(x_{k+1})-\log(x_k)\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty} \log\left(\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}\right)$$

Since the natural log is continuous at $1$, we may conclude

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_k}=e$$

Comment: What is $\gamma$

Comment: A constant equal to about $0.577216$. However, you add and subtract it so it disappears from the limit

Comment: @Robert-NicolaeSolca It's also known as the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Please add more details to $\lim_{k\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x_k}-k)=0$.

Comment: More details added

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach to the first answer that provides a more precise asymptotic:

I'll write $H_n = 1 + 1/2+ \ldots + 1/n$. It is known that
$$H_n = \log n + \gamma + o(1)$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. There therefore exists two sequences $\delta_n, \epsilon_n =o(1)$ such that
$$\log n + \gamma + \delta_n \le H_n \le \log n + \gamma + \epsilon_n.$$
Since $H_{x_n} \ge n$,
$$\log x_n + \gamma + \epsilon_{x_n} \ge n$$
which rearranges to $x_n \ge e^{-\gamma} e^{n +o(1)}$. Further, since $H_{x_n} \ge n$ then we necessarily have that
$$\log x_n + \gamma + \delta_{x_n} < n + 1/x_n,$$
since, if this does not hold, $H_{x_n} \ge n+1/x_n$ and $H_{x_n -1} \ge n + 1/x_n - 1/x_n =n$ contradicting the definition of $x_n$ (since $x_n -1$ would be smaller than $x_n$ and still satisfy your inequality). Hence, $x_n < e^{-\gamma} e^{n+1/x_n +o(1)}$.

Combining our inequalities gives that
$$ \frac{x_n}{e^n} \sim e^{-\gamma}.$$

Your question follows easily from this asymptotic expression.